# PHP socket_listen() not working

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu, xampp

I am trying to learn Socket programming in PHP. I got hold of a tutorial. I followed the precise code from the tutorial but my code returns

unable to listen on socket [22]: Invalid argument error.

I think it is more of a server error rather than bug in the code itself. I am running XAMPP Server in Ubuntu.

```
#!/opt/lampp/bin/php
<?php

// set some variables
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 80;

// don’t timeout!
set_time_limit(0);

// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die('Could not create socketn');

// bind socket to port socket_connect($socket, '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die('Could not bind to socketn');

// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die('Could not set up socket listenern');

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die('Could not accept incoming connectionn');

// read client input
//$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die(“Could not read inputn”);

// clean up input string
$input = "red";//trim($input);

// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) . 'n';
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die('Could not write output n');
echo ($output);

// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to listen to a port, not do an outgoing connection, your `socket_connect` should instead be `socket_bind` (which your comment already suggests)

```
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die('Could not bind to socketn')
```

Also, you should be aware that listening to a port below 1024 requires you to run the script as root (not really recommended for experimenting), so you may want to change to a port above 1024 to be able to run as a regular user.

Comment: The script is running without any error. Do you expect the output 
    echo ($output);
to be printed? The script returns me no output  as if in a infinite loop.

Comment: @user2267386 The script is waiting for something to connect to the port you're asking it to listen to. If you, for example, use `telnet localhost 8080` (assuming you liten to port 8080), you should see the output "dern" (red reversed + "n") in both telnet and output to the console. Then the script will exit.